# URL Rewriting for PHP script on an image URL

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite, template-redirect

I built an image randomizer so that when I open a .php file in a URL that it displays the image with `readfile($randomImage);`. This works locally but when I upload it to the server it gets blocked by the firewall since we do not want to be able to load URLs like

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/THEME/randomImage.php
```

I want to load a `.php` script on a `.jpg` file.
What needs to happen is that when I use the URL (for instance)

```
https://www.example.com/image.jpg
```

and when I load this image that it runs a PHP file like

```
https://www.example.com/randomizer.php
```

In other words, I want WordPress to think that it is loading a URL ending with `.jpg` but opens a `.php` file

Is this something that is realizable?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following at the *top* of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing WordPress directives:

```
# Internally rewrite "/image.jpg" to "/randomizer.php"
RewriteRule ^image\.jpg$ randomizer.php [L]
```

This uses mod_rewrite to rewrite the URL. There is no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive (that occurs later in the file).

Any request for `/image.jpg` (in the document root) is internally/silently rewritten to your `/randomizer.php` PHP script (also in the document root - assuming that is where your `.htaccess` file is located, *or* where the `RewriteBase` directive points to).

> I have a weird request maybe

This isn't weird at all. In fact, using URL-rewriting like this is probably preferable to linking directly to your PHP script. Although calling the URL `random-image.jpg` or something similar maybe a good idea.

This is actually pretty much identical to a question I answered yesterday on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340667/htaccess-redirect-one-file-to-another-including-query-string

Comment: Does this mean that there must be a file like image.jpg? Or does it work without its existance

Comment: "there must be a file like image.jpg?" - absolutely not. In fact, if `image.jpg` did exist then it will not be accessible since all requests are sent to `randomizer.php` instead.

Comment: And how does routing work with the RewriteRule? I mean how do I specify the location of my randomizer.php file?

Comment: You can specify a root-relative URL-path (or file-path) - less the slash prefix (optional) - as the 2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive. eg. If the target file is `https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/THEME/randomImage.php` then specify `wp-content/themes/THEME/randomImage.php` in the `RewriteRule` directive. (However, this can depend on what other directives you have in your `.htaccess` file.)

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: Project was on hold for a while, working on it again now though.

I got it working locally though I cannot find a way to make it work on the server. We use the same .htaccess files for other projects as well so if there is a possibility to do this without editting the .htacces and do it within the code that would be the perfect sollution for me.

Answer (score -1):

I created a function named randomImage() that simply takes a random image from an array, this function gets called in with the function below:

```
function imageRedirect(){
// Get the page name from the URL
$page = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

// Make sure debug mode is disabled since the deprecation errors will ruin the photo content
if (WP_DEBUG) throw new Exception('Due to depreciation errors this photo can only be rendered with debug mode disabled!');

// If we're on the random image page
if ($page == RANDOM_IMAGE_URL) {

    // Fetch a random image and return the data
    $image = randomImage();

    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($image));
    readfile($image);

    exit;
}
}
```